# How to swap specific pairs of data across rows in R/Python based on another dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I want to swap values across specific pairs of data across rows using R or Python. I have a first dataframe containing line by line trials, and a second dataframe which is a reference list for the order of the words presented in the trials. As some of the word pairs in the first dataframe are not in the correct order, I would like to swap specific pairs of words that are not in order based on the second dataframe.

The first dataframe looks like this:

```
SN    word1   word2 

1     dog      cat 

2     mouse    rabbit

3     sheep    goat 

4      ox      snake  

5     cat      dog
```

I have a second dataframe that looks like this:

```
word1   word2

 cat    dog

 mouse  rabbit

 sheep  goat

 snake  ox
```

What I would like to do is swap certain values across the rows of the first dataframe such that the words are in the order specified by the second dataframe. For example, the second dataframe specifies that cat is "word1" and dog is "word2", so if there is an instance in the first dataframe where dog is "word1" and cat is "word2", I would like for the order of the words to be switched.

The final output should look like this:

```
SN    word1   word2 

1     cat      dog 

2     mouse    rabbit

3     sheep    goat 

4     snake    ox  

5     cat      dog
```

Is there a way to achieve this in R or Python? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two dataframes are called `df1` and `df2`, one way would be to sort the words in both the dataframe alphabetically and perform the join. Finally keep the order present in `df2`.

In R, you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(sort_col1 = pmin(word1, word2), 
         sort_col2 = pmax(word1, word2)) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
            mutate(sort_col1 = pmin(word1, word2), 
                    sort_col2 = pmax(word1, word2)), 
            by = c('sort_col1', 'sort_col2')) %>%
  transmute(SN, word1  = word1.y, word2 = word2.y)

#  SN word1  word2
#1  1   cat    dog
#2  2 mouse rabbit
#3  3 sheep   goat
#4  4 snake     ox
#5  5   cat    dog
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(SN = 1:5, word1 = c("dog", "mouse", "sheep", "ox", 
"cat"), word2 = c("cat", "rabbit", "goat", "snake", "dog")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(word1 = c("cat", "mouse", "sheep", "snake"),
word2 = c("dog","rabbit", "goat", "ox")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```